# Dictionary is full! error message using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello I'm truying to do somthing on a dictionary,

here is a head :

```
           V1 V2 V3  scaf_name
1: scaffold_0  1  1 scaffold_0
2: scaffold_0  2  1 scaffold_0
3: scaffold_0  3  1 scaffold_0
4: scaffold_0  4  1 scaffold_0
5: scaffold_0  5  1 scaffold_0
6: scaffold_0  6  1 scaffold_0
```

and here is the code I tried:

```
tab3<-tab %>% 
    group_by(scaf_name) %>%  
    summarise(Avg_group=mean(V3),Length=last(V2))
```

and here is the error message I got

```
Error: Internal error: Dictionary is full!
```

here is the dimension of the tab

```
> dim(tab)
[1] 852355422         4
```

So it seems that the dataframe is to huge to use dplyr, does someone know how can I overcome the issue ?

thank you very much

here is a short part of the df

```
> dput(tab_bis)
structure(list(V1 = c("scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0"), V2 = 1:30, V3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), scaf_name = c("scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", 
"scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0", "scaffold_0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x556f4666b340>)
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: @akrun sure I added a short extract fo the df at the end

Comment: With that data, I am not getting an error.  May be it is the size that matter

Comment: Yes sure, see there is 852 355 422  rows in the real data, maybe someone knows a way to do the same thing but with huge data as this one ? ...

Comment: As it is a data.table, have you tried `data.table` methods i.e. `tab[, avg : mean(V3), scaf_name]`

Comment: @akrun well I do not know how to do the same thing as I use with dplyr in data.table, do you knwo a such similar code ?

Comment: I meant `tab[, avg := mean(V3), scaf_name][, .(Avg_group=mean(V3),Length=last(V2)), scaf_name]`. Also, not clear wy the 'avg' column is created and then not used in `summarise`

Comment: @akrun I tried you code ```tab_test<-tab[, avg := mean(V3), scaf_name][, .(Avg_group=mean(V3),Length=last(V2)), scaf_name]``` and got the error 
```Error in gforce(thisEnv, jsub, o__, f__, len__, irows) : 
  Internal error: Failed to allocate counts or TMP when assigning g in gforce``` and you are right for the avg columns its a duplicate

Comment: Could be an issue with memory

Comment: Do you not see my answer. This is not a memory problem as more of int32 in spite of int64 used by dplyr for hashtable.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue already known by a tidyverse.
https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/issues/1133
You bypass the limit on a certain value. They have to fix it.
`... uint32_t. I thought about just making sure that we store this instead as a uint64_t ...`
And with example
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5291

My solution will be to use data.table.

```r
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(tab)
dt[,.(Avg_group=mean(V3),Length=last(V2)),by = .(scaf_name)]
```

Comment: I dot not really get the issue here, is mean that I cannot use dplyr for this issue and the dplyr team is actually trying to correct the issue right ?

Comment: Yes, they trying to solve it. Might be better option to use data.table where the problem should not exits.

Answer (score 0):

Use data tables, it's better for handling huge chunks of data